# How can I convert a text selection to upper case in Apple Mail with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, mail.app, applescript

Apple Mail version Version 6.6 (1510)
OS 10.8.5

Is there a keyboard shortcut for converting the case for a text selection in the message editor? I know I can right-click and access this from the transformations menu

Comment: Well it wont be easy but doable. You will need a script that does that, then make a keyboard shortcut to run it.

Comment: There is a possible answer to this question here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380605/script-to-convert-lower-case-characters-into-upper-case-is-working-differently-a

Answer (score 1):

Create `~/Library/KeyBindings/`, save

```
{
  "~=" = uppercaseWord:;
}
```

as `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`, and quit and reopen Mail. It makes ⌥= convert the selection or the word around the cursor to uppercase.

See http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html or http://osxnotes.net/keybindings.html for more information.

Answer (score -4):

Go to Format → Change Case.

Comment: The OP stated that they knew this way of solving the problem.